# Concatenate values based on ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I Have a table called Results and the data looks like:

```
Response_ID    Label
12147          It was not clear
12458          Did not Undersstand
12458          Was not resolved
12458          Did not communicate
12586          Spoke too fast
12587          Too slow
```

Now I want the ouput to display one row per ID and the values from Label to be concatenated and seperated by comma

My Output should look like:

```
Response_ID    Label
12147          It was not clear
12458          Did not Undersstand,Was not resolved,Did not communicate
12586          Spoke too fast
12587          Too Slow
```

How can I do this:

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can not be sure about the order of the strings concatenated without an order by statement in the sub  query. The `.value('.', 'varchar(max)')` part is there to handle the case where `Label` contains *XML-unfriendly* characters like `&`.

```
declare @T table(Response_ID int, Label varchar(50))
insert into @T values
(12147,          'It was not clear'),
(12458,          'Did not Undersstand'),
(12458,          'Was not resolved'),
(12458,          'Did not communicate'),
(12586,          'Spoke too fast'),
(12587,          'Too slow')

select T1.Response_ID,
       stuff((select ','+T2.Label
              from @T as T2
              where T1.Response_ID = T2.Response_ID
              for xml path(''), type).value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 1, '') as Label
from @T as T1
group by T1.Response_ID
```

Comment: Good point about .value, I always make assumptions about data in the question being broadly representative. It doesn't cause an error, of course, just displays the entity (e.g. &amp;). However I am not so sure order was important to the OP - and what order by would you add, if it were? We'd need more information.

Comment: @Aaron – Yes, we need more info about the order. I was just making a point to @Sam that even though this sample code concatenates the string in the expected order, there is no guarantee that it will do so every time.

Comment: THis is not a good solution because it is a performance problem when there are many rows in the table. XML functions are slow.

Answer (score 1):

Check the link below, it approaches your problem with many different solutions

http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/

Answer (score 1):

Given this sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE #Results(Response_ID int, Label varchar(80));

INSERT #Results(Response_ID, Label) VALUES
  (12147, 'It was not clear'),
  (12458, 'Did not Undersstand'),
  (12458, 'Was not resolved'),
  (12458, 'Did not communicate'),
  (12586, 'Spoke too fast'),
  (12587, 'Too slow');
```

On older versions you can use `FOR XML PATH` for (grouped) string aggregation:

```
SELECT r.Response_ID, Label = STUFF((SELECT ',' + Label
    FROM #Results WHERE Response_ID = r.Response_ID
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value(N'./text()[1]', N'varchar(max)'), 1, 1, '')
  FROM #Results AS r
  GROUP BY r.Response_ID;
```

If you are on SQL Server 2017 or greater, the query is much simpler:

```
SELECT r.Response_ID, Label = STRING_AGG(Label, ',')
  FROM #Results AS r
  GROUP BY r.Response_ID;
```

Answer (score -1):

Consider this, it is very performant:

http://jerrytech.blogspot.com/2010/04/tsql-concatenate-strings-1-2-3-and.html

Avoid XML functions because they are not performant.

This will take some effort to implement, but millions of rows => milliseconds to run.

Comment: @jerry-nixon-msft , I didn't downvote you, but I did see some discussion about the performance of a recursive CTE vs For XML here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13639262/optimal-way-to-concatenate-aggregate-strings
It appears that For XML is faster on large datasets.