# T-SQL String Concatenating multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Simulating group_concat MySQL function in MS SQL Server 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-ms-sql-server-2005)
>   [Concatenate values based on ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6603319/concatenate-values-based-on-id)

I am trying to write a SQL query in SSMS 2008 to group by a single column.  I have a table with just two columns: Part Number and Product Code.  Both of these columns are VARCHAR data types.

Right now my table looks something like:

```
Part Number              Product Code
111222                   AAAAA
111222                   BBBBB
111222                   CCCCC
111223                   AAAAA
111224                   AAAAA
111225                   AAAAA
111226                   DDDDD
111226                   EEEEE
```

But I want this table to instead look like:

```
111222                   AAAAA, BBBBB, CCCCC                 
111223                   AAAAA
111224                   AAAAA
111225                   AAAAA
111226                   DDDDD, EEEEE
```

How do I do this? I have read some websites recommending coalesce function, but I can't seem to figure out a way to get this to work correctly.

Answer (score 11):

several approaches here http://web.archive.org/web/20120429052520/http://www.projectdmx.com/tsql/rowconcatenate.aspx

The article details far too many approaches to list in this answer however my favorite approach is this one:

> **The blackbox XML methods**
>
> An example for string concatenation using FOR XML clause with PATH
>   mode is detailed below. It was initially posted by Eugene Kogan later
>   became common in public newsgroups.

```
SELECT p1.CategoryId,
      ( SELECT ProductName + ',' 
          FROM Northwind.dbo.Products p2
         WHERE p2.CategoryId = p1.CategoryId
         ORDER BY ProductName
           FOR XML PATH('') ) AS Products
  FROM Northwind.dbo.Products p1
 GROUP BY CategoryId ;
```

> Again, the similar approach originally found in the beta newsgroups, using CROSS APPLY operator.

```
SELECT DISTINCT CategoryId, ProductNames
  FROM Products p1
 CROSS APPLY ( SELECT ProductName + ',' 
                 FROM Products p2
                WHERE p2.CategoryId = p1.CategoryId 
                ORDER BY ProductName 
                  FOR XML PATH('') )  D ( ProductNames )
```

> You may notice a comma at the end of the concatenated string, which you can
>   remove using a STUFF, SUBSTRING or LEFT function. While the above
>   methods are deemed reliable by many at the time of writing, there is
>   no guarantee that it will stay that way given the internal workings
>   and evaluation rules of FOR XML PATH() expression in correlated
>   subqueries are not well documented.

Comment: And the link has now changed!

Comment: @bgolson changed the link to show source info and a quick except. In these situations in the past I've been discouraged by mods from copying the article.

Comment: @M_M Thanks so much for the update!  Probably not good to copy directly, but maybe apply what you found there and use it your own solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
DECLARE @ProductCodeCSV as varchar(max)

select @ProductCodeCSV = COALESCE(@ProductCodeCSV + ', ', '') + [product_code]
from table
where part_ = 34175--@ID

select @ProductCodeCSV
```