# How to concatenate values with same id in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

My table contains the details like with two fields:

```
User ID  Rolename
1        Editor
1        Reviewer
7        EIC
7        Editor
7        Reviewer
19       EIC
19       Editor
19       Reviewer
```

I want get the unique details with `RoleName` like

```
1 Editor,Reviewer
7 EIC,Editor,Reviewer
```

How to combine `RoleName` Details? How to write the Query?

Comment: What database system and which version are you using??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Concatenate values based on ID](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6603319/concatenate-values-based-on-id)

Comment: Thanks to all.I got the answer.SELECT DISTINCT U.UserID, U.FirstName + ' ' + U.LastName AS Name,Mobile,Email,UserName,
        SUBSTRING((SELECT ', ' + A.RoleName FROM NZF_UserRoles A INNER JOIN NZF_RolesForUsers B ON A.RoleID=B.RoleID AND B.UserID = U.UserID
        FOR XML PATH ('')),3,1000) AS RoleName    
      FROM NZF_Users U
  ORDER BY UserName ASC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These both links help u to do this task :

http://jahaines.blogspot.com/2009/07/concatenating-column-values-part-2.html 
http://jahaines.blogspot.com/2009/06/concatenating-column-values-part-1.html