# Concatenate Sql column

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.assessement_group_id,
                b.title as dataa
FROM assessment_group a
JOIN assessment_category b
WHERE a.assessement_group_id = b.group_id
```

I am using the join to display the data.the result are shown below

```
100     Partner Business Profile
99      Partner Activation
99      ajay test
100     ajaytest123
```

But i want this type of answer

```
   100   Partner Business Profile,ajaytest123
   99     Partner Activation,ajay test
```

Comment: Duplicate question. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8516212/how-to-concatenate-values-with-same-id-in-sql) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6603319/concatenate-values-based-on-id) answere.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Results as comma separated list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/662207/mysql-results-as-comma-separated-list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ...)` along with `GROUP BY` to get the output you want:

```
SELECT a.assessement_group_id,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT b.title)
FROM assessment_group a
INNER JOIN assessment_category b
    ON a.assessement_group_id = b.group_id
GROUP BY a.assessement_group_id
```

## SQLFiddle

By the way, I replaced your old-style implicit join syntax with an explicit `INNER JOIN`.  It is generally considered bad practice now to put join conditions into the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Try something as follows, hope this helps

```
select id, group_concat(`dataa` separator ',') as `dataa`
from
(
  SELECT distinct a.assessement_group_id id, b.title as dataa 
  from assessment_group a JOIN assessment_category b 
  WHERE a.assessement_group_id=b.group_id
) tbl
group by id;
```

Answer (score 0):

See the MySql `GROUP_CONCAT()` as part of a *grouped* query.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html

You would add a `GROUP_BY assessement_group_id` to the end of the query, for example.

Answer (score 0):

In mySql you can use the GROUP_CONCAT function, see here more details: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat.

In your initial query you need to add GROUP_CONCAT(b.title) in select clause and also a group by after assessement_group_id.

Answer (score 0):

This one will help you

```
 SELECT A.ASSESSEMENT_GROUP_ID, GROUP_CONCAT(B.TITLE SEPARATOR ' , ') AS DATAA FROM  ASSESSMENT_GROUP A, ASSESSMENT_CATEGORY B WHERE A.ASSESSEMENT_GROUP_ID=B.GROUP_ID GROUP BY A.ASSESSEMENT_GROUP_ID;
```