# Concatenating with line breaks in single cell

Tags: sql, sql-server, concatenation

The link below will be helpful to understand my question. As pooja mentioned about her output like a concatenated string, is it possible to get a new line after each concatenation like

```
1  Editor
   Reviewer
7  EIC
   Editor
   Reviewer
```

the roles should be in a single cell though.

I have tried using `char(13)` and `char(10)`, but there is always something mismatch
with SQL Server 2012 I am using: 
[How to concatenate values with same id in sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8516212/how-to-concatenate-values-with-same-id-in-sql?answertab=active&newreg=cde3df51301a43b8ad90b5302cecd290)

Can anyone please help?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the mismatch you are getting? char(10) should work, as should '\n'.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (id int,
                  name NVARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO @T 
VALUES(1,'JAMES'),
(1,'HARRY'),
(2,'CO'),
(2,'VT'),
(2,'SC')
;

SELECT id,STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT(','+B.name) 
              FROM @T B
              WHERE B.id = A.id
              FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'' ) AS name
FROM @T A
GROUP BY id
;
```