# Concatenating rows into single column when taking value from two different tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Concatenate values based on ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6603319/concatenate-values-based-on-id)

I have two tables

**table1** contains

```
pkUserSubjectid  UserId  fkSubjectId
   15              146     1
   16              146     2
   17              146     4
   18              147     1
   19              147     3
   20              148     1
   21              148     3
   22              149     1
   23              149     3
```

**table 2** contains

```
pkSubjectId   SubjectName
      1        Maths
      2        English
      3        Physics
      4        Chemistry
      5        Computer
```

I want my result in this format

```
 UserId     SubjectName
   146       Maths, English, Chemistry
   147       Maths, Physics
```

and so on

Please tell me any query in SQL

Comment: so you want your work done for you?

Comment: Depending on the DBMS you use there are different solutions. What do you use? SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, SQLite, PostgreSQL or perhaps something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider building a clr aggregate function. The msdn example function would work for this.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131056(v=sql.100).aspx

You could then do something like

```
SELECT a.[UserId], dbo.MyAgg(b.[SubjectName]) as [SubjectName] 
FROM table1 as a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 as b ON a.[fkSubjectId] = b.[pkSubjectId] 
GROUP BY a.[UserId]
```

The example uses a single parameter and uses "," as the delimiter. You could also create a 2 parameter function as in the second example to pass in the delimiter.