# Iterating through a SQL Server 2008 R2 table variable and concatenate values

Tags: sql, loops, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table variable `@Holding` two columns: an `id` (not unique) and a `message`:

```
id     message
----   -------
2      give
2      me
2      help 
3      Need
3      help
1      help!
```

The result should be

```
2     give me help
3     Need help
1     help!
```

This it very much simplified, but shows that there are id which may exist more than once, and some kind of text which should be concatenated into a string.

I cannot manage it to loop through this table variable (but not through a table too!).

I tried a cursor (which I did not understand correctly) but it failed of course.
The number of records are not that much, not even 100 in that table variable.

Thanks yr. help
Michael

Comment: Which RDBMS? oracle, MySQL? SQL SEerver? mySQL can do this using group_concat, oracle WM_CONCAT, and maybe for xml path in SQL Server.  but this wouldn't guarantee order, there's no implied order in the above...

Comment: Sorry, I edited it: it is a SQL Server 2008R2

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL group\_concat function in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8868604/sql-group-concat-function-in-sql-server)  Again though order of the text in the message is not guaranteed! or dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-sql-server

Comment: possible duplicate of [Concatenate values based on ID](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6603319/concatenate-values-based-on-id)

Answer (score 0):

This should work if you are using SQL Server.

```
 select T1.id,
   stuff((select ' '+T2.[message]
          from @A as T2
          where T1.id = T2.id
          for xml path(''), type).value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 1, '') as [message]
 from @A as T1
 group by T1.id
```

Answer (score 0):

[Original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6603319/concatenate-values-based-on-id)

**No CURSOR, WHILE loop, or User-Defined Function needed**.

Just need to be creative with FOR XML and PATH.

[Note: This solution only works on SQL 2005 and later. Original question didn't specify the version in use.]

```
CREATE TABLE #YourTable ([ID] INT, [Name] CHAR(1), [Value] INT)

INSERT INTO #YourTable ([ID],[Name],[Value]) VALUES (1,'A',4)
INSERT INTO #YourTable ([ID],[Name],[Value]) VALUES (1,'B',8)
INSERT INTO #YourTable ([ID],[Name],[Value]) VALUES (2,'C',9)

SELECT 
  [ID],
  STUFF((
    SELECT ', ' + [Name] + ':' + CAST([Value] AS VARCHAR(MAX)) 
    FROM #YourTable 
    WHERE (ID = Results.ID) 
    FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)')
  ,1,2,'') AS NameValues
FROM #YourTable Results
GROUP BY ID

DROP TABLE #YourTable
```

Comment: Thanks both of you, it works!
 But frankly, I do not understand WHY!

Comment: @Tiger955 keep in mind that this only performs well with a low amount of rows. Also look into FOR XML Path, and the STUFF command to understand how it works.

Comment: @ ZeRaTuL_jF: thanks, the number of rows will not exceed 20 per run.
And YES, I already found the function STUFF and FOR XML Path.

Great new experience for me! Thanks

Comment: @Tiger955 Please, can you pick the answer)

Answer (score 0):

Pretty the same, just less letters in the code:

```
DECLARE @t AS TABLE ( id INT, msg VARCHAR(100) );

INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES     ( 2, 'give' );
INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES        ( 2, 'me' );
INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES        ( 2, 'help' );
INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES        ( 3, 'Need' );
INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES        ( 3, 'help' );
INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES        ( 1, 'help!' );

SELECT DISTINCT
    id ,
    (
      SELECT ST1.msg + ' '
      FROM @t ST1
      WHERE ST1.id = ST2.id
    FOR XML PATH('')
    ) t
FROM
    @t ST2;
```